# How to hide a Pydantic discriminator field from FastAPI docs

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

We have a discriminator field `type` which we want to hide from the Swagger UI docs:

```
class Foo(BDCBaseModel):
    type: Literal["Foo"] = Field("Foo", exclude=True)
    Name: str

class Bar(BDCBaseModel):
    type: Literal["Bar"] = Field("Bar", exclude=True)
    Name: str

class Demo(BDCBaseModel):
    example: Union[Foo, Bar] = Field(discriminator="type")
```

The following router:

```
@router.post("/demo")
async def demo(
    foo: Foo,
):
    demo = Demo(example=foo)
    return demo
```

And this is shown in the Swagger docs:
[image]

We don't want the user to see the type field as it is useless for him/her anyways.
We tried making the field private: `_type` which hides it from the docs but then it cannot be used as discriminator anymore:

```
    class Demo(BDCBaseModel):
  File "pydantic\main.py", line 205, in pydantic.main.ModelMetaclass.__new__
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 491, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.infer
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 421, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.__init__
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 537, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.prepare
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 639, in pydantic.fields.ModelField._type_analysis
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 753, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.prepare_discriminated_union_sub_fields
  File "pydantic\utils.py", line 739, in pydantic.utils.get_discriminator_alias_and_values
pydantic.errors.ConfigError: Model 'Foo' needs a discriminator field for key '_type'
```

Comment: possible answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911334/is-there-a-way-to-exclude-pydantic-models-from-fastapis-auto-generated-document

Comment: @Anentropic thanks, looks like an option.  We will try but it feels kind of hacky.  Maybe there is a more sophisticated way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common situation and the solution is farily simple. Factor out that `type` field into its own separate model.

The typical way to go about this is to create one `FooBase` with all the fields, validators etc. that all child models will share (in this example only `name`) and then subclass it as needed. In this example you would create one `Foo` subclass with that `type` field that you then use for the `Demo` annotation, and one `FooRequest` class without any additions.

Here is a full working example:

```py
from typing import Literal, Union

from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class FooBase(BaseModel):
    name: str

class FooRequest(FooBase):
    pass  # possibly configure other request specific things here

class Foo(FooBase):
    type: Literal["Foo"] = Field("Foo", exclude=True)

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

class Bar(BaseModel):
    type: Literal["Bar"] = Field("Bar", exclude=True)
    name: str

class Demo(BaseModel):
    example: Union[Foo, Bar] = Field(discriminator="type")

api = FastAPI()

@api.post("/demo")
async def demo(foo: FooRequest):
    foo = Foo.from_orm(foo)
    return Demo(example=foo)
```

Note that I used the `orm_mode = True` setting just to have a very concise way of converting a `FooRequest` instance into a `Foo` instance inside the route handler function. This is not necessary. You could also just do `foo = Foo.parse_obj(foo.dict())` there.

Also, the addition of the `FooRequest` model is redundant here of course. You can just as well use the `FooBase` as the request model. I wrote it this way just to demonstrate a typical pattern because sometimes the request model has additional things that distinguish it from its siblings. In your example it is overkill.

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to exclude the discriminator field from OpenAPI docs thanks to the Pydantic [schema customization](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/schema/#schema-customization)

```py
from typing import Any, Literal, Union

from fastapi import APIRouter
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

router_demo = APIRouter(prefix="/demo", tags=["demo"])


class BDCBaseModel(BaseModel):
    # ...

    class Config:

        @staticmethod
        def schema_extra(schema: dict[str, Any], model: type["BDCBaseModel"]) -> None:
            # https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/schema/#schema-customization
            properties = schema.get("properties", {})
            if "type" in properties:
                del properties["type"]


class Foo(BDCBaseModel):
    type: Literal["Foo"]
    Name: str


class Bar(BDCBaseModel):
    type: Literal["Bar"]
    Name: str


class Demo(BDCBaseModel):
    example: Union[Foo, Bar] = Field(discriminator="type")


@router_demo.post("/demo", response_model=Demo)
async def demo(
    foo: Foo,
):
    return Demo(example=foo)
```

The resulted documentation does not expose discriminator fields:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the base concept. If you model is modeling the parameters of an API, and you discriminate which model to use based on the value of parameter "type", then the API user must (it is a required field) send that key! Why do you want to hide it anyway?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the setup. `Foo` is what is sent **to** the API and `Demo` is what is returned. The `type` field on `Foo` is optional with its default (and only possible) value being the string `"Foo"`. That is why it makes little sense to force the user to send it along with the `name` field.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple and correct way to do it just using annotations

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.json_schema import SkipJsonSchema


class Bar(BaseModel):
    fiels_a: SkipJsonSchema[str] = Field(exclude=True)
    field_b: str
```

**field_a** will be excluded from the docs